# Доступ с Composer, идущим в комплекте с Open Server из Php Storm

Tags: php, phpstorm, composer, openserver

Я знаю, что Open Server имеет в комплектации консоль, откуда есть доступ к Composer. Тем не менее, я бы хотел обойтись без этой консоли и работать с Composer через PHP Storm.

В "Language & Frameworks", я указал путь с исполняемому файлу Composer:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запуска "composer -V" через "Tools -> Run Command" пока возникает ошибка "Can not run program composer".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Можно ли обойтись без указания новой системной переменной / переменной окружения?
- Если нет, то какую именно переменную окружения надо задать?
- Если для доступа к composer из Php-Storm нужны ещё какие-либо действия, то какие?

Comment: Вы пробовали через [Command Line Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-tool-support.html) его запускать?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, да. Результат такой же (добавил скриншот с сообщением об ошибке в поле ответа).

Comment: Для работы компосера из PhpStorm, как и для работы любой другой утилиты командной строки, требуется соблюдение обычных условий, диктуемых операционной системой: либо она доступна для запуска просто командой composer (т.е. путь к ней прописан в переменной ОС path), либо указывается полный/относительный путь к файлу composer). Только что проверил у себя в терминале Шторма. Прекрасно выполняется без ошибок. Ubuntu, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример конфигурации:

[image: PHPStorm - Command Line Tool Support]

А вот пример ввода начала команд в ней:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используйте полные пути для PHP и Composer.phar, и всё работает без переменных окружения.

Как проверить что это сработало? - PHPStorm сам запустит обработку команд и извлечет доступные варианты.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Принял и проголосовал.